# What does ɴᴏᴛ count as a “neopronoun”?

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct, english

Recently I have come across the curious neologism ***neopronouns***. I have
a lifelong interest in languages and linguistics, but this is a new concept
for me.  Prior to a month or so ago I had never heard of ‘neopronouns’.

Quite a number of years ago I did come across the form *hesh(e)*.
I have never to date seen this word used in practice, so
I’m unsure whether it does, or does not, qualify as a neopronoun.

My question is a straightforward one, and I would very much appreciate
if all answers to it would please remain on topic.

## My Question

What is ɴᴏᴛ a neopronoun, and if anything can be said ɴᴏᴛ
to be a neopronoun, then what authorities or official bodies might
decide this and via what specific criteria?

---

### Background

A little more explanation of my motivation to ask this question,
since this question has not led to many answers, but has provoked
a great number of comments:

- Language is organic. We are right to adopt a descriptive rather
  than a prescriptive approach to language because language as it
  is used by its speakers *is* the language.
- It follows that neopronouns in use are already de-facto elements
  of the living languages in which they are used.
- But mass adoption of new language elements by the public at large relies
  in no small degree on their adoption by both the print and the spoken media
  alike, and then using these elements frequently and consistently to
  familiarise the general public with them.
- Media adoption of new language elements depends on those elements being
  presented in clear, uncontroversial forms to enable their widespread
  adoption. Few today would find controversial the marriage-nonspecific female
  honorific *Ms* from the mid-twentieth century, nor would anyone alive
  today find controversial the inanimate third-person possessive personal
  pronoun *its* which was first written that way during the late sixteenth
  century – sex being an intrinsic property only of animate beings alone, not of 
  inanimate objects for which *it* and *its* are rightly used in the
  singular.
- A surprisingly high number of animate but still gender-nonspecific
  neopronouns have been proposed since the mid-nineteenth century.  All seek 
  traction, although none of them – presumably because of their novelty and
  rarity and because of competition from the many others which makes each
  individual pronoun all the rarer – ever manage to achieve that traction.
  They simply do not stick.

  The idea of an animate gender-nonspecific third-person personal pronoun is
  uncontroversial: we never question that we today use gender-nonspecific
  first- and second-person pronouns, *I*, *we*, and *you* – or the archaic
  and dialectal forms *thou* and *ye*.

  Consequently we might hypothesise now in the early 21st century that
  today’s media have failed to adopt any animate but gender-nonspecific
  third-person personal pronouns (which are less rare and novel than they
  once were) because of substantial confusion and lack of clarity over the
  overwhelming number of rival proposals.
- It occurs to me (and probably to many others) that some of the confusion
  might be cleared up – and the chances of media adoption and then mass
  public adoption greatly increased – if exactly what is ɴᴏᴛ and ᴄᴀɴɴᴏᴛ ᴇᴠᴇʀ
  be considered a neopronoun were made clearer. I recognise this takes us
  into the realm of linguistic prescription, which we are usually right to avoid.

  Allowing doubt and confusion to proliferate explosively alongside competing
  proposals hinders mass adoption of what could be otherwise presented as a
  useful set of animate yet gender-nonspecific third-person subject, object,
  reflexive, possessive, and determinative pronouns with universal
  application by all speakers of English.

  These would be analogous to how in
  most dialects of present-day English we now universally use second-person
  *you* for males and females alike rather than reserving second-person *you*
  only for those scenarios in which we do not care to specify their gender and some
  hypothetical form like *❉shyou* for females with a corresponding
  hypothetical form *❉hyou* for males when we actually ᴅᴏ care to specify their gender.

Comment: There is an SE site for English language (https://english.stackexchange.com/), shouldn't this question be there instead?

Comment: By my understanding anything can be a neo-pronoun and there is no "official" body which approves it, I believe it's done through community consensus.

Comment: @Tom I'm guessing it's related to the CoC but OP just hasn't tagged it as such.

Comment: "new" = new. So a "neo pronoun" is a new pronoun. That's compared to the non-new ones - "he", "she", "it". As far as I know, there is nothing that officially says "this new pronoun is official, the other isn't".

Comment: [This](https://nonbinary.wiki/wiki/English_neutral_pronouns#Neopronouns) should give you an idea. There are also [nounself pronouns](https://nonbinary.wiki/wiki/Nounself_pronouns).

Comment: @Tom makes an entirely reasonable suggestion. Do neo-pronouns exist only in the English language? If neo-pronouns only exist in the English language, I will move this question to english.stackexchange,com. (I am not currently a member).

Comment: @Rounin Yes, the terminology "neopronouns" is certainly specific to the English language, although similar concepts might exist in other languages too.

Comment: Thanks. Please note my question relates to the concept, rather than the English word which labels the concept.

Comment: @Rounin In any case, this question doesn't seem to be relevant to this site unless you're asking some clarification regarding the CoC. If yes, edit to clarify. Otherwise, delete and ask on the language sites instead.

Comment: This question emerges from many recent discussions relating to the CoC but no, I don't want to start yet another discussion about the CoC. Instead I want to ask one particular question, the answers to which may then inform other discussions which _are_ explicitly about the CoC. If the consensus is that I should move this question to linguistics.stackexchange.com, I am happy to do so (though it may then become less visible to the participants of other discussions in Meta, which are explicitly CoC-related).

Comment: Though the concept applies to languages other than English, asking it in the English site is probably a good idea anyway, as the specifics of the answers depend on which language one is dealing with (other languages, for instance, might have official regulatory bodies, or handle pronouns in a very different way). A sufficiently general form of this question might work on [the linguistics site](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/), as long as it doesn't end up too broad.

Comment: @Script47 Yes that's might be true, but still doesn't discuss if those pronouns should be used or not (which would be a meta topic), but what they are, so I still think it would be better suited for the linked SE page.

Comment: @Rounin No, I don't think neo-pronouns are limited to English only, but the main language on most Stack Exchange sites is English, so it would still be best asked there and if needed additional questions on non-English sites. Or like duplode suggested, on https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: There is no authoritative instance for the English language like other languages that have them. Even then these instances follow the evolution of the language.

Comment: This question doesn’t really make sense—what is your question?

Comment: Who decides what is or isn't a cromulent adjective in English? Neither a committee governing the English language, nor the writers of *The Simpsons*, but English speakers collectively, somehow.

Comment: This cannot possibly be off-topic at the moment.

Comment: @Stormblessed - I would like to understand what is and what isn't a valid neo-pronoun. (Not just in English as JeroenMostert refers to, but in other languages, be they Indo-European, Finno-Ugric, Altaic etc.) My starting point is that "Any combination of letters (or ideograms such as Prince's symbol) is not a neo-pronoun solely because one or more individuals say it is." My next question, if we accept this contention, is: "What doesn't qualify as or meet the criteria of a neo-pronoun?" I also accept that the starting point itself is open to debate.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Although English lacks any equivalent to a body like _L'Académie française_, there are, nevertheless, authoritative publications (eg. the _Associated Press Style Guide_) which might reach influential decisions regarding standard English language usage (eg. _website_ vs. _Web site_).

Comment: @Rounin: and while that's true, nobody would claim that the Associated Press Style Guide *decides* that henceforth it shall be written *website* and not *Web site*, in the sense that that can be reasonably expected to dictate the usage among the majority of English speakers (educated or not). If you wanted to extend this to neo-pronouns, or any other frontier of the English language, the question would reduce to a list of publications people consider "authoritative" on the matter -- possibly even *internationally*. A tall order -- I think individual studies are the best you could hope for.

Comment: To put it another way: if you're asking if there are global authorities on the use of neo-pronouns that cover the topic across languages, I think the answer's a clear "no" unless we're willing to accept the credentials of the individual academics who might actually be considered such authorities -- but even then they'll likely be studying the phenomenon, not handing out proscriptions.

Comment: Sure, I'm not going so far as to suggest that the English language is presided over by a prescriptive body like _L'Académie française_ or the Japanese Ministry of Justice (which determines rules on kanji use in baby names). The _and [...] what authorities / official bodies might decide [...]_ is a subsidiary and non-essential part of my question above. Please ignore it if it distracts from the main question: _What isn't a neo-pronoun?_

Comment: I can't post this as an anwser, but here is an academic peer reviewed listing [known neoprouns](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/34a7/07a9a8b26267cd35e1adb3f9ce54d25ee34c.pdf) from the Journal of language works.

Comment: That question is essentially non-answerable unless we answer it trivially ("something that isn't used as a new pronoun") or we frame it in a context, like the "neo-pronoun or trolling" question does. It's like asking *what is and isn't a valid neologism?* At the time of coining, they're all valid or all not valid, depending on your point of view. What happens afterwards then depends. The linked duplicate is appropriate if your interest is in what it means for SE in practice. The more general linguistic question would belong on a general linguistic site.

Comment: Perhaps it would be more enlightening to pin down just what it is that the referenced so-called ***"new" "pronouns"*** actually **are** before attempting to say what they are **not**. //  It's also probably worth noting that the layman and the linguist are apt to understand these terms and their instances rather differently, leading to confusion and conflict.

Comment: I am working on the basis that a neo-pronoun is: _"a letter (or glyph) or a combination of letters (or glyphs) used to address or refer to an individual with non-binary identity."_

Comment: As far as most people in the LGBT+ community are concerned, neopronouns are pronouns other than she, he, or they.

Comment: Thank you. My question above is not _"What is a neo-pronoun?"_ but _"What isn't a neo-pronoun?"_ That is to ask: what are the formal linguistic (or other) criteria for a neo-pronoun (however broad), such that when presented with something that isn't a neo-pronoun a reader may say: "That isn't a neo-pronoun."

Comment: __N.B.__ _Nothing_ ___is___ a legitimate answer to this question. It seems entirely reasonable to me that an individual might take the position that "Nothing isn't a neo-pronoun." Before asking my question above however, I'm already assuming this isn't actually anyone's real-world point of view. I'm happy to see my assumption corrected if there is in fact an established body of opinion which holds that _"Nothing is not a neo-pronoun."_

Comment: @Rounin Your assumption is contested in several comments and also [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336013/622738) in the duplicate target.

Comment: @Goyo - Thank you. I'm not seeing anything which provides formal linguistic (or other) criteria which determines whether a letter (or glyph) or a combination of letters (or glyphs) legitimately represents or doesn't represent a neo-pronoun.

Comment: @Rounin As I understand it there are no other criteria for legitimacy than somebody asking you to use that combination of glyphs as pronouns to address them.

Comment: A neopronoun is a proposed pronoun which has not been grammaticalised into the speech community's language.

Comment: @Rounin I don’t understand why your question mentions “descriptive” use. Nobody appears to have suggested anything descriptive here that I’ve read. There appears to be no discernible intent to describe anything at all. The Code of Conduct is not about **descriptive** use of neopronouns; it’s only about **prescriptive** use of neopronouns and **proscriptive** use of paleopronouns. For descriptive, you’d need [something linguistical](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/34a7/07a9a8b26267cd35e1adb3f9ce54d25ee34c.pdf) and preferably peer-reviewed.

Comment: _Descriptive_ as in, if an English language user adopts the Elverson 1975 pronoun set (ey, eir, em, eirs, emself), we cannot say these pronouns don't exist in the English language, since, by virtue of the fact that and English speaker is using them, they do. _Prescriptive_ is an approach to language which declares native speakers to be using the language correctly or incorrectly, as if there were some canonical version of the language outside how it is used in the real world.

Comment: @Rounin Descriptive linguistics still makes calls about whether things are commonly used or are parts of a various varieties of the language including the standard variety. It is very likely that some neopronouns have been grammaticalised in a dialect spoken in queer communities. That doesn't mean they're grammatical in the broad international English of the SE network.

Comment: @weakdnasaysreinstatemonica Are 'I', 'you' 'it' and 'we' neopronouns?

Comment: @Inactive-ObjectingExtremism No, those are not neopronouns because they developed organically. Nobody ever invented them. This is why the so-called “singular *they”* works so well: it developed organically over centuries of common use. Nobody ever invented it.

Comment: Why was the title edited with a weird font?

Comment: I understand, thanks. I was just trying to point out what I thought might be an oversight in the earlier comment by @weakdnasaysreinstatemonica.

Comment: @Inactive-ObjectingExtremism I meant third person pronouns.  Also, "it" is usually not regarded as a valid pronoun and it is seen as disrespectful to call someone whose pronouns are unknown as an "it".

Comment: @weakdnasaysreinstatemonica Ah yes, third person pronouns makes sense, thanks for the response. Sorry to be so pedantic, but I think in the current climate it does matter. Also "it" most certainly *is* a pronoun. Of course it is normally not used to refer to a person, and I agree that it is generally disrespectful to use it to refer to a person.

Comment: @Inactive-ObjectingExtremism Oh, yes, I know it's a pronoun that exists, I'm just saying that many queer and trans folk agree that it isn't the *correct* or *valid* way to refer to anyone.  There's a small percentage of nonbinary people who choose to call themselves "it", but most of us... aren't on board with that.

Comment: Relevant article on this topic from June 4th, 2021: https://www.theatlantic.com/culture/archive/2021/06/gender-neutral-pronouns-arent-new/619092/ The lesson from history remains: if we can't determine what *isn't* a neo-pronoun, then, instead of evolving a linguistically useful set of neo-pronouns with widespread usage and recognition, we are doomed to live with a large number of proposals, none of which ever achieve widespread public traction.