# Where is the most recent version of the Code of Conduct?

Tags: support, behavior, code-of-conduct

Is https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct (dated 10 October 2019) the most current available Official StackExchange Code of Conduct in its entirety? Does it include the recent gender pronoun and other changes, or does it predate that?

If I behave in accordance with the 10/10/2019 Code of Conduct, will I be in compliance with SE rules?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct is always up-to-date.

Comment: @Mast given the level of ambiguity and gone missing links to Official SE FAQs lately, as well as diamond moderator posts going missing, I feel the need to have some reassurance that the CoC dated 10/10/2019 is in fact up to date in an actual answer. I know you're right, that that URL *was* always up-to-date these past nine years I have been a user, but SE and SO are not in the usual operating mode, for various reasons.

Comment: There's nothing sinister in posts going missing, in fact the reverse, to keep the site clean and have more clarity. Rather than multiple `faq` posts, they have the one canonical one. There's more to trust here than people want to give credit to. But I'm a lone voice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The up-to-date Code of Conduct is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct. As you can see it includes reference to gender-neutral pronouns and stated pronouns.

The FAQs associated with pronouns have been updated and the new version is at [What does the Code of Conduct say about pronouns?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336364/195988).

You can respond to the FAQs here: [Post for clarifications on the updated pronouns FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336366/195988)