# At what other sites do people discuss Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, meta

I occasionally read comments that seem to imply there are other places on the Internet where the Stack community has discussions.  Other than the occasional Medium post I'm not aware of these.

Do these places exist?  Where are they?

I'd be interested in both Stack users and non-Stack users.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

On reddit there is a dedicated subreddit and it also shows up in the programming subreddits.

- https://www.reddit.com/r/stackoverflow/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/search/?q=Stackoverflow&restrict_sr=1
- https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/search/?q=stackoverflow&restrict_sr=1

Twitter

- https://twitter.com/search?q=%23stackoverflow

Youtube comment discussion
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFiQPkdb5Qs

And of course GoFundMe

- Link unavailabe due to SE policies, but Googling `Monica Cellio GoFundme` will bring it up.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338270/why-is-se-removing-links-and-community-ads-about-legal-issues

Comment: There are also various Discord servers, Slack servers, etc

Answer (score 8):

After the drama/exodus on [Ru.SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), which happened earlier and is unrelated to the current CoC/ads/Monica events on SE (but which shared the same root problem of administration disregarding community), some Ru.SO's users migrated from the official chat to an unofficial Zulip chat.

Anyone interested can find the link in profiles of some of top users of Ru.SO. (I'd rather not include the link here directly to avoid accidental visits, as most MSE users aren't probably interested in a Russian chat.)

We got tired of administration removing Meta posts and chat messages, so we found a new place where we can discuss SO without censorship.

Comment: I'm sorry to be so dense, but I couldn't find the link on anybody's profile.  Would you mind mentioning the link here or sending me an email?  My address is in my profile.

Comment: @MarkHarrison You can find it in either [my profile on Ru.SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176051) or profile of the [top user of all time](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105).

Answer (score 5):

[Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/news) is a discussion forum or social news site with a community of users interested in thoughtful discussions on a wide variety of interesting topics with a primary focus on technology, startups/business. Naturally, there’s an overlap between its readers and Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange users. Here are are some recent discussions on Stack Exchange itself:

- [I'm Resigning as a Stack Overflow Community Elected Moderator](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21288421)
- [An apology to our community, and next steps](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21175225)
- [Is Stack Exchange in violation of NY labor law by using volunteer moderators?](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21397014)
- [Stack Overflow is doing me ongoing harm](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21340965)
- [Stack Overflow Inc. Fiasco: Timeline](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21173643)
- [On the way to being the most downvoted post ever on StackOverflow:Meta](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21251573)
- [Official StackOverflow FAQ on Gender Pronouns and Code of Conduct Changes](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21232460)
- [An apology to our community, and next steps](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21175225)
- [An Update to Our Community and an Apology](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21153224)

Regular question-and-answers are also commented on and discussed, e.g.,

- [Which answer in this list is the correct answer to this question?](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21543377)
- [My name causes an issue with any booking](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21490850)
- [How to Discipline Overeager Engineer?](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21117031)

---

[List of all submissions from stackexchange.com](https://news.ycombinator.com/from?site=stackexchange.com&next=20572536)

Answer (score 4):

Hackernoon [has mentioned it](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d)

Dev.to also has [some articles on the site](https://dev.to/codemouse92/has-stackoverflow-become-an-antipattern-3icb)