# Are we doing anything but spinning our wheels?

Tags: discussion, community

There is no real conversation between the users here and the management of SE, and has not been for, what, six weeks?  **Both groups are out of their depth.**

We are out of our depth because we have no route to open up a conversation with management, and all we can do is express frustration and disagreement -- often eloquently to be sure, but almost always in a way that I think must harden opposition to us, and a resolve to simply wait us out.

Management is out of its depth too, and I think that is because they have delegated too far down the line.  Whether this is deliberate and they are happy to be sending a message to us that they don't care, or whether they are following legal advice, or whether they think that, for example, The Loop is really terrific....we can't tell because they are being a black hole.

***If we are spinning our wheels what is the first step to gain traction?***

**I suggest that the very first step is to find out whether Monica's legal representative has made any headway,** and, if not, are we being unreasonably impatient?  Is this just the speed at which these things go? Ideally we could get some feeling for how long it will be before before First Non-Form-Letter Mutual Contact, without jeopardizing Monica's case.

The present state is not productive.  We are banging our heads against a brick wall in total darkness.

Comment: I mean, what do you expect, you're fighting for something that will never happen.

Comment: You might as well waste your breath. SE have lawyered up and have zero intention of making a statement beyond the (bland) one that's already been posted

Comment: To quote a Vorlon: "The avalanche has already begun, it is too late for the pebbles to vote".

Comment: This is likely one of the more sane posts I see here.  All the rest seem devoted to creating more polarization.

Comment: The [last word](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338271/282094) about it.

Comment: What makes you think that this vehicle should gain traction? What makes you think the driver cares?

Comment: What is life other than spinning our wheels? Does it matter where we come from, where we go, or whether we move at all? When the wheels stop spinning it's all over. Our fingernails don't really keep growing. Take lots of photos when you're young.

Comment: Are we a wheel or a drill? A drill moves forward with every rotation, gaining ground bit by bit.

Comment: We are the drill and the hole.

Comment: "If we are spinning our wheels what is the first step..." Stop spinning. And then have a good look. And then do something else (some non-spinning).