# What do you want to see from Stack Exchange in 2021 and beyond?

Tags: discussion, company

Inspired by [Shog's contest here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360327/contest-what-was-the-most-impactful-change-on-stack-exchange-in-2020) (which is my excuse for asking about this *now* – It's almost February!).

We've had many posts reflecting on the follies and triumphs of the past. We have roadmaps from the company.

While we have a few structures for feedback – formal and informal, it might be nice for us *as the community* to talk about the sort of things we would like to see in 2021 and beyond, whether practical or aspirational.

Knowing what we know now, and the changes, good and bad that have happened over the past year (and before) - what do we want out of the network in the coming year?

Obviously – as a community-led, completely unofficial post, there's no promise any of this will happen, and there's obviously some stuff that can't realistically happen, but what do you'all want from the *future*? <sub><sub>Flying cars aside. We all want flying cars</sub></sub>

Comment: Inspired by Shog's contest.... so what is the prize here? ;)

Comment: Alas, all my swag is well used . So, nothing more than the use of a soapbox

Comment: Surely used hat can be washed and used by others..... :D

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Or one of your socks.

Answer (score 16):

There is probably more that I wish for, but right now following two things are on top of my list:

- more guidance for the new users before they ask their first question - this is actually on the roadmap and hopefully it will be adequate to reduce inflow of poor posts on Stack Overflow
- ability to migrate old, highly visited, off topic questions to the appropriate site - with coordination between sites - in other words, ability to remove off topic content, while preserving value

Comment: +1, especially the "More guidance for asking your first question".

Comment: +1000 for that first bullet point!

Answer (score 6):

#### Area 51.

[Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) needs lots of love, or if things are beyond repair, it should get a [euthanasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euthanasia). It's just suffering, and bleeding bugs for years.

Comment: What are some of the main bugs?

Comment: @P.Mort nothing really "main", but it was made clear they won't fix bugs as the codebase is "old" so I'm pretty sure people don't even bother to report bugs on Area 51 anymore. I don't.

Answer (score 3):

## Maintain Stack Exchange mobile apps: iPhone and Android.

**SEE ALSO:**
[How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348075/578690)
[Questions tagged with [android-app] or [ios-app] or [mobile-app]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app+or+ios-app+or+mobile-app)

Comment: If it’s just for the mobile notifications, there is the [Push Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API); Stack Exchange can become a [Progressive Web App](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps) instead of a stand-alone app.