# How does the photo widget work?

Tags: support, moderator-tools

The photo widget on photo.se seems to only exist on that site. My site (Arqade) has somewhat recently started doing Screenshot of the Week contests, and the widget would potentially be a good fit for promoting it on our site.
We also have [quite a lot of support from the community for adding it](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14925/do-we-want-to-enable-the-photo-widget-for-our-site).

However, there doesn't seem to be any documentation on how the widget works. The best I can find is [this post from '11](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/picture-of-the-week-no-longer-requires-a-funky-aspect-ratio), saying that the aspect ratio changed.

What features does the photo widget have, and how does it work?

Comment: It should be possible to enable it on other sites.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319274/323179

Comment: Distantly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340383/282094 - unless you want an identical feature resources may not be available to customize a new interface for additional sites. If you do want an identical UI there may be a delay to enable it.

Comment: There's also a contest on [Travel.SE](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-competition), [Photo.SE's info](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/114433/37074) doesn't explain the [tag:moderator-tools]; ***if*** that's what you are asking about you should add that tag to the question. Also a [link to the question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14925/225622) on Arcade.SE would be a good addition.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On Photo.SE we have a moderator utility "Custom Sidebar Content", a form which allows us to enter an image URL, a photo title, and the user's profile URL.

[image: Custom Sidebar Content moderator utility]

The widget displays the photo, title, and user name + link to their profile.

It also has links to our ongoing contest, another link to a "Hall of Fame" of previous contest winners, and a heading of "Photo of the Week".

[image: The Photo of the Week widget]

The heading and the 2 links are not configurable by us. The widget also doesn't provide any ability to click on the image to see a larger size, so that might be limiting for a screenshot.

And as for aspect ratio, there used to be strict requirements, but now the image is scaled to fit. I assume it maintains the original aspect ratio, and is scaled to have a maximum width within the sidebar.

Comment: This is great info. Thanks!