# Can we post links to Monica's GoFundMe page again now that donations to it are closed and she's reached an agreement with SE?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, legal

In mid-November, SE [began removing links to Monica Cellio's GoFundMe campaign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338270/377214), under the direction of their legal team.

However, today, the campaign has been closed and is no longer accepting donations, much of the original criticism against SE that was in its opening statement has been removed, and it has been updated to reflect the fact that she's reached an agreement with SE.

Given these recent developments, are we free to post such links now, or will they still be removed? What does the legal team have to say about it?

Why would one want to be able to post such links today and later? SolveIt [said it perfectly](/posts/comments/1140082):

> People will talk about this series of events for a long time, and linking the [GoFundMe] page for context and information is a natural thing to do. Now that this is all over, it's pretty much a historical record.

Comment: What would be the point now? Or, are you just curious?

Comment: @Script47 Yes, I'm curious.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog typical Sonic :P

Comment: @Script47 People will talk about this series of events for a long time, and linking the gofundme page for context and information is a natural thing to do. Now that this is all over, it's pretty much a historical record.

Comment: No seriously, what would be the point?

Comment: @Makoto SolveIt said it perfectly.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog - I'm unconvinced.  Crowdfunding campaigns are often temporal in support of something else.  There's ***copious*** historical information on the site already, and I'm really not seeing the point to adding this to the list.

Comment: @Makoto The question here is not *why* would one want to put up such a link. Rather, it's "if one wants to put up such a link now, will it still have to be removed for legal reasons?"

Comment: Please stop questioning the appropriateness of the question. If you feel that the question is not useful, you can downvote it. That's what downvotes are *for*. If you want to debate the merits underlying the question, chat would be a better place.