# How should the new pronoun policy be applied to Spanish language?

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct, international-sites

For Spanish speaking users is not so simple. We don't have "he" or "she", we have *programadores* y *programadoras*, *arquitectos* y *arquitectas*, ....

We finish by using only masculine terms, because if not, as complained in this text a member of Spanish Royal Language Academy, this is what happens (I cannot translate this on a engine, try it if you wish):

> «El pleno está integrado por el presidente o presidenta, el vicepresidente o vicepresidenta y los vocales o las vocales.»
>
> Ante ese párrafo pueden ocurrir dos cosas. Una es que parezca normal: de pura saturación terminas acostumbrándote a cualquier imbecilidad. La otra es que nos dé la risa floja. Al principio creí que era un texto chungo. Manipulado. Pero nada de eso: BOPV, ley 9/2004 de la Comisión Jurídica. «Se hace saber a los ciudadanos y ciudadanas», etcétera. Todo trufadito de perlas como ésta: «Un secretario o secretaria que se nombra por el presidente o presidenta (...) entre funcionarios y funcionarias». Y más adelante, con repetición exhaustiva de las titulares o los titulares, las vocales o los vocales, los presentes o las presentes, el secretario o la secretaria, el presidente o la presidenta, se detalla que en ausencia «de uno de los vocales o una de las vocales (...) se procederá al nombramiento de un suplente o una suplente (...). El nombramiento y cese del suplente o la suplente se realizará conforme a lo previsto (...). El tiempo que dure la suplencia se imputará al período de mandato de la vocal o el vocal suplido».
>
> Imagino que las feministas galopantes estarán goteando agua de limón con el texto, pero creo que aún podríamos afinar un poquito más. Porque observo cierto déficit de concordancia. Puestos o puestas a ello, «la vocal o el vocal suplido» debería haberse escrito «la vocal o el vocal suplido o suplida», o bien «la vocal o el vocal suplidos o suplidas». Y puestos a hilar fino, lo de «el tiempo que dure la suplencia» también era mejorable escribiendo «el tiempo que dure la suplencia o el suplencio». Pero en fin. Cada maestrillo tiene su librillo.

[Arturo Pérez-Reverte. Las miembras y los miembros. *El Semanal*](http://www.perezreverte.com/articulo/patentes-corso/56/las-miembras-y-los-miembros/)

I think SE should clarify this new policy for non-English languages such as Spanish.

Comment: We have the same "problem" here in France, and so-called [inclusive writing](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2017/11/inclusive-writing-france-feminism/545048/) is supposed to be the "solution". That's not very popular, though.

Comment: For those not in *the loop* (snicker) Perez-Reverte's article above is a jibe at the politically correct idea, popular at the time in Spain, of using both the masculine and the feminine of each plural noun every time it appeared, "for inclusiveness", instead of the neutral form, which is identical to the masculine. As one can see, it leads to ridiculously long walls of text that contain very little actual information, but maximize the amount of virtue signalling per line, which one might suspect was the actual goal all along.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336364/369802? It states: `6. How does this apply to languages other than English?
While these specific requirements around pronoun usage apply only to the English language, the goal of being inclusive and respectful of all genders applies to all our communities. As we find best practices in other languages, we’ll work with those communities and update guidance for those languages.` (though that doesn't say much about what it means, just that it still needs work)

Comment: In french, almost everything is strictly gendered. I am a feminism and a lot of us are not sold by inclusive writing. It is cumbersome. You can be inclusive by using more neutral words. At the end, I dont think it is a hill I will die for. There are better fight to do.

Comment: To change a language (spanish for example), the use of what is to be changed should be very extensive. That so called "inclusive language" is not, at all, it it doesn't seem it would be in a near future. And (this is my opinion) not necessary at all, because in spanish the masculine is the "gender neutral" (genero no marcado)  that includes everyone.

Comment: You can also [include Portuguese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_neutrality_in_languages_with_grammatical_gender#Spanish_and_Portuguese) on this question.

Comment: German has the same problem, maybe with some different nuances. The typical solution is to use both versions: "Estimados programadores y estimadas programadoras ..." like.

Comment: This has already received some discussion on the Meta site of Spanish Language https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3231/how-should-we-address-people-in-spanish-in-a-gender-neutral-way-on-our-site

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the Code of Conduct say about pronouns?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336364/what-does-the-code-of-conduct-say-about-pronouns)

Comment: I am not sure if I should accept the duplicate. The point 6 only says they are going to give specifical guideliness for every non-english language. I am asking specifically what are those guideliness.There is a big debate on Spain about how to apply to institutional language Equality Law for men and women. The company is from USA.I am asking how they are going to apply it if academics of  Royal Spanish Academy say inclusive language cannot be performed so easy.Anyhow you know much more better than me how the site works and if it helps marck it as duplicate of the main post about pronouns.

Comment: To mix in another language: In German, the idea of using a "gender-neutral language" is not applicable. I mean, at all. Not the least. People are *trying* it, but the results are ridiculous abominations of the language that *real* people are *speaking* - in *reality* (you know, the thing where the pizza comes from). However, this is just a starter. People will insist of certain syntactical crutches, regardless of whether they make sense or not.

Comment: SE don't care. Spain isn't the USA. Therefore they don't care. Sorry.

Comment: @Lightness Races with Monica Spain is only a little part of spanish speakers. We are in 50 million habitants while only Mexico has 150 or so....

Comment: @Universal_learner Heh, irony. True, sorry, didn't mean to suggest otherwise.

Comment: Dear Universal_learner: What does it means "a reputable source" for you in the context of this specific question?

Comment: @Rubén it means nothing. I am not going to participate in any site unless [chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/users/18196/universal-learner?tab=profile) because I got a job on administration and it is tiring to me to follow english texts (I did it on Earth Science mainly to learn english and to put the profile on my CV) and wanted to offer some of the reputation I earned asking the question before closing my account.

Comment: As Jose Antonio don't want the rep, the points go to your account. I hoppe you are ok with that.After all I think I am free to offer a bountyI like both answers; maybe to use a gender neutral electricista is not ideal (same word for male and female). I like your answer *you can do it or no*. At Stackoverflow in sp they said tje CoC only applies to english

Comment: Greetings desde el otro lado del charco I programm a bit so if I have trouble not solved on other question may see you asking on stackoverflow in spanish. Cheers and happy coding everybody

Comment: @Lightness Races with Monica My english is too much limitated to understand that, (also I am asperger and I don't take the second senses), but well they should care aboput the entire spanish speakers community if they want to be inclusive

Comment: @Universal_learner Yep, I'm saying, I agree.

Comment: I don't think non-Spanish speakers should make policy on Spanish.  This question belongs on the Spanish site.  I will VTC this question on this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Super briefly, the "pronouns policy" is if someone asks for a specific pronoun to be used when someone talks to/about him/her/them we should use it, that's it.

There are two sites on the network where Spanish is allowed. If someone ask us to use "él/ella/ello/elle" when talk to/about "él/ella/ello/elle" basically we have two options

1. Use it
2. Walk away

The same applies to sustantives, adjectives and other words, is someone asks to refer to "él/ella/ello" as "programador/programadora",

1. Do it
2. Walk away

Actually, there is a third option, *ignore the request*, but then your account could be suspended or if you are ♦ moderator, the ♦ and the related privileges could be removed too.

By the way, if you have questions about how to inflect your adjectives in Spanish we could ask about that in https://spanish.stackexchange.com

---

From [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336368/289691) by [Cesar M](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/508266/cesar-m) one of the Community Managers, to [What does the Code of Conduct say about pronouns?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336364/289691)

> ### What's this all about? - The Basics
>
> This section is an explanation of singular third-person pronouns.
>
> #### 1. What's this business about "pronouns"?
>
> It would be rude to refer to a man as "she" or a woman as "he". Some people are neither men nor women and might, for instance, ask to be referred to as "they". When someone indicates what pronouns should be used to refer to them, please use the pronouns they state as you would others.

---

> #### 6. How does this apply to languages other than English?
>
> While these specific requirements around pronoun usage apply only to the English language, the goal of being inclusive and respectful of all genders applies to all our communities. As we find best practices in other languages, we’ll work with those communities and update guidance for those languages.

PS: I don't think that this month the CM will discuss the best practices in other languages. Please be patient.

References

- https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elle_(pronombre_propuesto)

Comment: The problem is that if someone asks me to use "ex" or some other neopronoun, how the heck do I inflect my adjectives?

Comment: @Mark That is a good question for the corresponding language site (if there is any)

Comment: @Mark the same way the rest of us have to apparently. Say things that are awkward, clunky, and sure to offend someone (probably).

Comment: @Mark the wikipedia article contains some inflected adjectives in Spanish.

Answer (score 25):

> How should the new pronoun policy be applied to Spanish language?

With uncertainty, since that is the new state of affairs in Stack Exchange...

> For Spanish speaking users is not so simple. We don't have "he" or "she", we have programadores y programadoras, arquitectos y arquitectas, ....

Not as if it is simple for english either as recent events reveal. We do have he->el and she->ella in spanish. But I agree, it can get even more complicated for us.
We also have gendered articles. Consider the gender-neutral phrase "**An** electrician did that".

- Male : "**Un** electricista hizo eso"
- Female : "**Una** electricista hizo eso"
- Non-binary, fluid or without gender : "**??** electricista hizo eso."
- Gender-neutral as per RAE(*) : "**Un** electricista hizo eso."
- Gender-neutral promoted recently : "**Un o una** electricista hizo eso."

There is the non-academic [Élle](https://es.wikihow.com/respetar-a-una-persona-transg%C3%A9nero) as a neo-pronoun for the 3rd case. But I have not found a spanish neo-article for the 3rd case.

> I think SE should clarify this new policy for non-English languages such as Spanish.

I think there is no need for that. We've been fine without that clarification. Maybe the mods of the spanish site could clarify if they've ever had to deal with miss-gendering or non-inclusive issues. I've seen none and would rather not fix a community which is not broken.
Also, I have no confidence in the current management of SE. Even if there was a problem here to be solved I'd rather them not being the ones addressing it.

Let our mods deal with it.

(*) RAE means [Real Academia Española](https://www.rae.es/) (Royal Spanish Academy). An academic institution widely but not universally accepted as the primary reference for spanish language. Their current stance is that in spanish masculine form serves both the functions of masculine and gender-neutral. RAE monitors and frequently incorporates evolutions in the language. It is fine to deviate from RAE's dictionary if you have a good reason, even academics do so.

Comment: As a quite interesting additional example:
A waiter did it (past tense).
El camarero lo hizo.
La camarera lo hizo.
?? camarer?? ?? hizo.

Comment: @Rubén Surely that should be *une gloriose pronombre propueste para une electriciste nueve*. :)

Comment: @tchrist Fortunately, regarding pronouns policy, the current SE sites that allows Spanish aren't about people jobs :D Anyway, just ask the user which article "él/ella/ello/elle" wants to be used when referring to "él/ella/ello/elle"

Comment: @Rubén Better hope they aren't un hombre o una mujer, un actor o una actriz, un rey o una reina who what you to go with that cursi (¿curse? :) ellé thinge then. :)

Comment: Related Spanish.Se Meta question:  [How should we address people in Spanish in a gender-neutral way on our site?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3231/5481). Also: [Should I avoid editing the forms including “@”, “x” and “-e” when/if seen in posts?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3233/5481).

Comment: To respond to `Maybe the mods of the spanish site could clarify if they've ever had to deal with miss-gendering or non-inclusive issues.` In my years as a [mod in that site](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3221/5481) it **never** was a problem. In fact, more problems (or the foreshadows of them) were created by the new (unclear, unpractical) policies + CoC. To this date it doesn't seem like a problem or even a concern. The main problem is that mods and users are unprepared to deal with any future problems and seemingly they have been given zero advice or support from the policy makers

Comment: Reverte would say "la electricista o el electricisto" :)

Comment: "We've been fine" -- I'm glad *you've* been fine. // I hadn't thought about the indefinite article.  Interesting point.

Comment: @Diego-ReinstateMonica - I agree that the botched roll-out of the new CoC was bad, very bad.  But there *was* a problem with pronouns during your tenure, and I haven't forgotten the support you and your co-moderator provided.  I do realize that for you it might not have seemed like a big problem, but it was for me, and your support was key.